# Given $A=(a,0)$, $B=(0,b)$, $C=(c,d)$, and $\angle B = 90^\circ$, find a relationship between $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$.

Tags: geometry

> The vertices of a triangle are at the points $A(a,0)$, $B(0,b)$, and $C(c,d)$, and angle $B$ has measure $90^\circ$. Find a relationship between $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$.

Can someone please help me figure this out. I'm not sure what method to use. I've tried Pythagoras and don't get the correct answer.

Comment: Ignore coordinates for a moment. If $\triangle ABC$ has a right angle at $B$, then how does Pythagoras relate $|AB|$, $|BC|$, $|CA|$? Once you have that relation, stop ignoring the coordinates, and express $|AB|^2$, etc, in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$.

Comment: You may get more and better responses, if you study [our guide to new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). You will also avoid many kinds of negative attention to your posts by following those guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors $(c,d-b)$ and $(a,-b)$ are perpendicular. Thus

$$(c,d-b)\cdot (a,-b)=0.$$ In other words

$$ac+b^2-bd=0.$$

Another way to solve it is to use that the vectors $(a,-b)$ and $(c,d-b)$ are the legs and the vector $(c-a,d)$ is the hypothenuse. Then

$$(c-a)^2+d^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+(d-b)^2.$$ Simplifying, we get

$$ac+b^2-bd=0.$$

Comment: Note that this relationship is not only implied by $\angle B=90^o;$ it implies that    $\angle B=90^o$..............+1

Comment: Thank you lots for this.